# Twig result/contents into string

Tags: string

I'm trying to adjust a google maps so have pins that correspond with my posts. I'm nearly there but I'm trying to load info into the info window. I can set it's content already by hand. And I have turned the info i want in the bubble into a html result. All I need to do is alter this so that the twig commands create a string I can pass on in the function that will add the pin.

So I'm trying to create a string result from the code below, which has all the results in it.

Here's what I got (and this works to produce the HTML I want to put in the info window of the pin:

—

```
{% set resultsNum = 0 %}

<h3>{{ block.location }}</h3>
<ul>
{% set searchString = block.location %}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('journal').find() %}
{% for block in entry.locations %}
    {% if block.type == "location" %}
        {% if block.location == searchString %}
            {% set resultsNum = resultsNum+1 %}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url() }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

—

The resulting string would go here (this code works already if i set my own string of html:

```
    {% set marker = {
    lat: result.geometry.location.lat,
    lng: result.geometry.location.lng,
    content: infoHTML 
    } %}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Which variables are you using to create a string?

Comment: None yet, but this generates the HTML I need to put into a string, which will go (see 2nd code block in first post)

Comment: So you need that entire HTML chuck as a string and not as rendered HTML?

Comment: Yes, exactly that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your HTML in a `{% set myString %}` block and use `myString` however you need too.

```
{% set myString %}
{% set resultsNum = 0 %}
<h3>{{ block.location }}</h3>
<ul>
{% set searchString = block.location %}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('journal').find() %}
{% for block in entry.locations %}
    {% if block.type == "location" %}
    {% if block.location == searchString %}
        {% set resultsNum = resultsNum+1 %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.url() }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endset %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's not entirely working for me yet. When I test out the string with {{ myString }} plainly on the page, it renders the same HTML. But passing it in the array, it goes awry. But when I copy the HTML from inspector and examine it, it contains some kind of hard enters? If that's a thing. What I see is couple of screen height empty pages and some spaces at the end. I just enclosed what I had with {% set infoWindowHTML %} and {% endset %} (so no copy/paste done) what could be causing these enters to be added? (Not talking about <br> just type enters of some sort) thanks again!

Comment: Maybe try Twig's [escape](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html#escape) filter ('e' for short). {{ myString|e('html') }} (html is the default I believe).

Comment: Figured it out by using string  | replace({"\n":"<br>"})

Thanks!